# How to re-use pre process jenkins/groovy in each test

Tags: shell, go, jenkins, groovy

Im using the following code to run our voter , currently I’ve one target which is called `Run Tests` 
Which use exactly the same steps as the **last (lint)** , currently I duplicate it which I think is not a good solution ,
Is there is nice way to avoid this duplication and done it only once as per-requisite process ?

I need all the steps until the `cd` to the project

The only difference is one target I run

```
go test ...
```

and the second

```
go lint
```

All steps before are equal

```
#!/usr/bin/env groovy

    try {
        parallel(
                'Run Tests': {
                    node {

                        //————————Here we start
                        checkout scm
                        def dockerImage = 'docker.company:50001/crt/deg:0.1.3-09’
                        setupPipelineEnvironment script: this, 
                        measureDuration(script: this, measurementName: 'build') {
                            executeDocker(dockerImage: dockerImage,  dockerWorkspace: '/go/src') {
                                sh """
                                mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/ftr/myGoProj
                                cp -R $WORKSPACE/* /go/src/github.com/ftr/MyGoProj
                                cd  /go/src/github.com/ftr/MyGoProj
                        //————————Here we finish and TEST
                                go test -v ./...                           
                                """
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
                ‘Lint’: {
               node {
                        //————————Here we start
                        checkout scm
                        def dockerImage = 'docker.company:50001/crt/deg:0.1.3-09’
                        setupPipelineEnvironment script: this, 
                        measureDuration(script: this, measurementName: 'build') {
                            executeDocker(dockerImage: dockerImage,  dockerWorkspace: '/go/src') {
                                sh """
                                mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/ftr/myGoProj
                                cp -R $WORKSPACE/* /go/src/github.com/ftr/MyGoProj
                                cd  /go/src/github.com/ftr/MyGoProj
                        //————————Here we finish and LINT
                               go lint
                              """

                }
                }
        )
    }

        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use function and pass Go arguments:

```
try {
    parallel(
        'Run Tests': {
            node {
                checkout scm
                runTestsInDocker('test -v ./...')
            }
        },
        'Lint': {
            node {
                checkout scm
                runTestsInDocker('lint')
            }
        }
    )
}


def runTestsInDocker(goArgs) {
    def dockerImage = 'docker.company:50001/crt/deg:0.1.3-09'
    setupPipelineEnvironment script: this, 
    measureDuration(script: this, measurementName: 'build') {
        executeDocker(dockerImage: dockerImage,  dockerWorkspace: '/go/src') {
            sh """
            mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/ftr/myGoProj
            cp -R $WORKSPACE/* /go/src/github.com/ftr/MyGoProj
            cd  /go/src/github.com/ftr/MyGoProj
            go ${goArgs}                        
            """
        }
    }
}
```

**Update**

If some actions can be separated out of `runTestsInDocker` they probably should be.

For example `setupPipelineEnvironment` step. I don't know exact logic but maybe it can be run once before running test.

```
node {
    stage('setup') {
        setupPipelineEnvironment script: this
    }
    stage ('Tests') {
        parallel(
            'Run Tests': {
                node {
                    checkout scm
                    runTestsInDocker('test -v ./...')
                }
            },
            'Lint': {
                node {
                    checkout scm
                    runTestsInDocker('lint')
                }
            }
        )
    }
}


def runTestsInDocker(goArgs) {
    def dockerImage = 'docker.company:50001/crt/deg:0.1.3-09'
    measureDuration(script: this, measurementName: 'build') {
        executeDocker(dockerImage: dockerImage,  dockerWorkspace: '/go/src') {
            sh """
            mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/ftr/myGoProj
            cp -R $WORKSPACE/* /go/src/github.com/ftr/MyGoProj
            cd  /go/src/github.com/ftr/MyGoProj
            go ${goArgs}                        
            """
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**

If you are running parallel on remote agents you must remember that setup performed on master may be not aviailable on remote slave.

Comment: Thanks, but still the commands (pre-process) will be called twice , I want to reduce the time if possible

Comment: Do you mean `setupPipelineEnvironment` step? I don't know the exact logic, but you could call it on beggining of your pipeline (before the parallel step).